# Using HQL to transpose data from one table to another

Tags: hadoop, hive, pivot, hql

I currently have a table that looks something like this:

Table_1

```
ID|NAME|INFO_CODE_1|INFO_CODE_2|INFO_CODE_3|INFO_CODE_4|INFO_TEXT|DESCRIPTION
1 |Test|123        |254        |556        |867        |Test Text|Test Description
```

I'm trying to insert the data in Table_1 into Table_2 so that each record from the first table turns into four separate records in the second table, like so:

Table_2

```
ID|NAME|INFO_CODE|INFO_TEXT|DESCRIPTION
1 |Test|123      |Test Text|Test Description
1 |Test|254      |Test Text|Test Description
1 |Test|556      |Test Text|Test Description
1 |Test|867      |Test Text|Test Description
```

There are many thousands of records in Table_1, there are other columns whose data we are not concerned with, and the values in INFO_CODE_1 through INFO_CODE_4 all vary from record to record (and may even be null). I was thinking about writing something like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE example.TABLE_2
SELECT
A.ID AS ID,
A.NAME AS NAME,
A.INFO_CODE_1 AS INFO_CODE,
A.INFO_TEXT AS INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
example.TABLE_1 A
UNION ALL
SELECT
A.ID AS ID,
A.NAME AS NAME,
A.INFO_CODE_2 AS INFO_CODE,
A.INFO_TEXT AS INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
example.TABLE_1 A
UNION ALL
SELECT
A.ID AS ID,
A.NAME AS NAME,
A.INFO_CODE_3 AS INFO_CODE,
A.INFO_TEXT AS INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
example.TABLE_1 A
UNION ALL
SELECT
A.ID AS ID,
A.NAME AS NAME,
A.INFO_CODE_4 AS INFO_CODE,
A.INFO_TEXT AS INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
example.TABLE_1 A;
```

1. Would this work?
2. If yes, is there a better way of writing the
   statement?
3. Is there a way to ensure that all records with the same ID are inserted one after the other?

Thank you all in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Refer to this? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView

Answer (score 0):

Another way with out much unions is this. It will require 1 mapreduce jobs instead of several jobs saving resources. You can concat your codes, split them to generate an array and explode the array.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE example.TABLE_2
SELECT
a.id,
a.name,
CODE
a.INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION from 
(
SELECT
A.ID AS ID,
A.NAME AS NAME,
split(concat(A.INFO_CODE_1, ",",A.INFO_CODE_2,",",A.INFO_CODE_3,",",A.INFO_CODE_4),",") AS INFO_CODE_ARRAY,
A.INFO_TEXT AS INFO_TEXT,
A.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION
from TABLE_1
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(INFO_CODE_ARRAY) codea AS code;
```

Comment: This solution has gotten me most of the way there, though I am encountering some problems.  

Omitting the INSERT portion of the statement returns a correct data set. For example, if the info code columns have the values 1, 0, 3, and 5 respectively for the first record, I'll get four separate rows, each with the corresponding value.  

1  
0  
3  
5  
However, if I include the INSERT portion of the statement, I still get four rows, but the records are inserted in reverse order, and it seems to hit a snag when it has to insert a 0, instead resulting in something like this  
5
3
0
0